# MySQL's CRC32 function output changes with the same input?

Tags: mysql, crc32

Essentially in my MySQL database I have Strings where the first letter is capitalized. They are stored as VARCHARs. For some reason when I use the CRC32 function on a word such as "action" I get a specific number. When I run the same CRC32 function on LOWER("Action") I get a different number.

So when I use the following query:

```
SELECT genre, CRC32( genre ) AS genre1, LOWER( genre ) AS
genre2, CRC32( LOWER( genre )) AS genre3
FROM `films`
WHERE 1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

I get the following output:

```
genre   |   genre1      |   genre2  |   genre3

action  |   1204587666  |   action  |   1204587666

Action  |   1252886437  |   action  |   3017532915
```

As you can see the CRC32 of "action" changes from when it is initially lowercase to a different value when it is changed from MySQL's LOWER function. genre3 in row two should be equivalent to genre1 and genre3 in row one.

Why is this happening? Is there anyway to make the CRC32(LOWER("Action")) equivalent to CRC32("action")? (I need CRC32(LOWER("Action)) to output 1204587666, I can't have CRC32("action") output 3017532915)

Comment: Since CRC32('Action') is 1080068516, not 1252886437, I'm assuming you have some other garbage character in your string. Fix that and it'll probably work just fine.

Comment: Garbage character as in a Control Character? I attempted to strip the String of all control characters before it is put in the database in php with preg_replace('/[\x00-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F]/', '', $genre); this didn't change the output of the CRC32 function when I ran the same query. Any suggestions on how to check to see if there is a garbage character or removing it in php?

Comment: Instead of trying to filter out control characters I just filtered out anything non-alphanumeric. Then it worked, thank-you for your suggestion!